# Understanding the very basic "loop" code in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I stuck on one task that involved making a loop in order to print all values (squared) based on the User's first input. My code did a pretty good job in printing the values, HOWEVER... they were printed upside-down.

Could someone help me understand the difference between these two approaches?

Below you can see the actual "description of the exercise" and the code I have wrote for the mentioned exercise.

**Edit:** Adding the Task description as requested.

**Task**:

The provided code stub reads and integer, **n**, from STDIN. For all non-negative integers **i < n** , print **i²**.

**Example**:

***n = 3***

The list of non-negative integers that are less than n = 3 is [0,1,2]. Print the square of each number on a separate line.

**Input Format**:

The first and only line contains the integer, **n**.

**Constraints**:

1 ≤  n ≤ 20

**Output Format**:

Print  lines, one corresponding to each **i**.

**Edit:** Leaving the link to the screenshot, just in case.
[Hacker Rank exercise description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trOfc.png)

I have tried the following part of the code:

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    print(n * n)
    n = n - 1
```

But the one below worked out as expected:

```
n = int(input())

for n in range(n):
    print(n * n)
    n = n - 1
```

Comment: @EdwardPeters no it is not. Python does not have block scope. There is no shadowing going on, `for n in range(n)` *assigns* to the same exact variable that `n` that is assigned to in `n = int(input())`. They exist in the same namespace, in this case, the global namespace.

Comment: the last line is useless in the second version

Comment: You should be using `i` in your loop body, not `n`.

Comment: Please post the problem description as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Note that `n = n-1` has no effect in the second version, because each iteration of the loop resets `n` to the next value from `range(n)`.

Comment: Why don't you use `print(i * i)` ? `i` is the incrementing number you want to print. There's no reason to decrement n

Comment: Thank you all for your input!
I have checked and confirmed that the "n = n - 1" is not necessary for the code to work and the advice with sticking to "i" variable in the loop body seems to be working fine as well.

Comment: Note [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) -- we expect each question to be about a single, narrow, specific technical question. Including your whole assignment distracts from the question itself -- make sure you're focusing narrowly on a single question about Python-the-language.

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem, in the first description you use "i" as your loop body instead of "n" (from your second loop), but in the first one you don't change the `print(n*n)` to `print(i*i)`. Along with the last line, change all the n's into i's. Here is the new code:

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    print(i * i)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You don't need the `i = i - 1`.

Comment: I'll delete it (sorry)